# ¿Cómo detectar qué elemento es Infinito en un vector (posición)?

Tags: r

Tengo un data frame en el que he detectado que una de las columnas contiene algún caracter infinito, mediante la siguiente función:

```
is.finite.data.frame <- function(obj){
  sapply(obj,FUN = function(x) all(is.finite(x)))
}
```

Al ejecutar esta función en mi conjunto de datos obtengo: FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, por lo que algún valor de la primera columna es infinito. ESto me parece bastante raro, ya que se trata de una variable tipo caracter: "NM_...". El problema ahora es que no consigo detectar qué elemento es infinito para eliminarlo. He intentado transformar los infinitos en NA, para luego usar "na.omit" pero no funciona.

Alguien sabe algún método para solucionar este problema de los valores infinitos?

Comment: Gracias a la respuesta de Patricio me he dado cuenta de que mis valores tampoco eran infinitos. No son finitos pero tampoco: Inf, NA, o NaN. Por lo tanto no se que puede estar ocurriendo. Se trata de una columna de 3.500.000 filas con objetos de tipo caracter. He probado a transformar la variable en factor pero tampoco se soluciona el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El tema esta bien explicado en la ayuda de [is.finite()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/is.finite.html):

> is.finite returns a vector of the same length as x the jth element of
> which is TRUE if x[j] is finite (i.e., it is not one of the values NA,
> NaN, Inf or -Inf) and FALSE otherwise. Complex numbers are finite if
> both the real and imaginary parts are.

Es decir `is.finite` retornará `FALSE` no solo con `Inf`  y  `-Inf`, sino también con los `NA` y `NaN`, ejemplo:

```
> is.finite(c(NA, NaN, Inf, -Inf)) 
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

`is.infinite()` no es complementaria de la función anterior, ya que retorna `TRUE` solo en el caso de `Inf`  y  `-Inf`, lo cual es justamente lo que estás buscando.

```
> is.infinite(c(NA, NaN, Inf, -Inf)) 
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Con esto en mente, podemos hacer un ligero cambio a tu función, negando el `is.infinite()`

```
is.finite.data.frame <- function(obj){
  sapply(obj,FUN = function(x) all(!is.infinite(x)))
}

mtcars[1,1] <- Inf
is.finite.data.frame(mtcars)

  mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb 
FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

El otro tema que observo, es que la función solo te retorna en que columnas hay algún valor infinito, tal vez sea más útil ubicar las filas y columnas dónde esto ocurre:

```
is.infinite(as.matrix(mtcars))

                      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
Mazda RX4            TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Mazda RX4 Wag       FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Datsun 710          FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Hornet 4 Drive      FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Hornet Sportabout   FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Valiant             FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Duster 360          FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Merc 240D           FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Merc 230            FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Merc 280            FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Merc 280C           FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Merc 450SE          FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Merc 450SL          FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Merc 450SLC         FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Cadillac Fleetwood  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Lincoln Continental FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Chrysler Imperial   FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Fiat 128            FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Honda Civic         FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Toyota Corolla      FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Toyota Corona       FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Dodge Challenger    FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
AMC Javelin         FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Camaro Z28          FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Pontiac Firebird    FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Fiat X1-9           FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Porsche 914-2       FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Lotus Europa        FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Ford Pantera L      FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Ferrari Dino        FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Maserati Bora       FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Volvo 142E          FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

O bien, en que fila hay un `Inf`

```
which(apply(is.infinite(as.matrix(mtcars)), 1, any))
```